# JQuery Functions Accessable by other JS Files

Tags: jquery, html, css

For my CSS I'm building several smaller files for specific functions and then using minification to combine and compress them into one file for download.

I would like to do the same with my JS Files - logical separation and then combine and compress with MIN for download.

The only catch I have is the AJAX based site I'm building has one core JS file that takes requests to load pages in the main viewing area.

Am I able to call this function (which is in one JS file) from other JS files? Its kind of like making one JS file public to the other scripts.

Any advice?

thx

Update**************

So how would I call a function in one JS file from another.

eg:

File A has function callmetoday()

How do I call this from within JS file number 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Unless you declare a function or variable inside a function or as an object field, it resides in the global scope. In case of a browser, that's the `window` object.

Note also the warning by Darwayne: you can only use a function from a different file after it has been declared (and in [some browsers](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) even within a file).

Example:

file 1.js:

```
function f1(x){
  f2(x)
}

document.addEventListener("load",function(){f1(3)})
```

file 2.js:

```
function f2(x){
  alert(x)
  if(x) f1(x-1)
}
```

will work:

- when 1.js is loaded, `f1` appears in the global scope
- when 2.js is loaded, `f2` appears in the global scope
- when the page is fully loaded, `f1` and `f2` are accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just make sure you load the dependency js files first.

If you're looking for a more "patterny" solution, may I interest you in looking at [requirejs](http://requirejs.org), which is a library that will assist you in solving such dependency issues.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are able to load functions from two separate js files, here's the catch:

The function must already be declared before you can use it

Which means you will either need to have the js file with the functions that you want to run, loaded before the js file that calls it..... or make sure you call the function after the page has fully loaded